# ADO.NET Long running transactions

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions, ado.net

I'm using Dapper, but this applies the same to ADO.NET code.

I have an operation on a web app that changes a lot of state in the database. To ensure an all-or-nothing result, I use a transaction to manage this. To do this, all my `Repository` classes share a connection (which is instantiated per request). On my connection I can call `Connection.BeginTransaction()`.

However, this operation can sometimes take a while (say 10 seconds), and it's locking some frequently-read-from tables while it does it's thing. I want to allow other repos on other threads to continue without locking while this is happening.

It looks like I need to do 2 things to make this happen:

1) Set the `IsoloationLevel` to something like ReadUncommited:

```
_transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

2) For all other connections that don't need a transaction, I still need to enroll those connections in a transaction, so that I can again set `ReadUncommited`. If I don't do this then they'll still lock while they wait for the long running operation to complete.

So does this mean I need ALL my connections to start a transaction? This sounds expensive and sub-performant. Are there other solutions I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: "Set the IsoloationLevel to something like ReadUncommited:" - DO NOT do that. If this is a SQL Server database (which I assume it is), what is the DB default isolation level? Has RCSI been turned on?

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that there is a trade-off between using locks or not, it's about performance vs concurrency control. Therefore, I don't think you should use `ReadUncommited` **all the time**.

If you try to use `ReadUncommited` on all other transactions that need not to be blocked by this long running transaction, they will by accident **not be blocked also by other transactions**.

Generally, we use this isolation level when performance is the first priority and **does not need data accuracy**

> I want to allow other repos on other threads to continue without
> locking while this is happening.

I think you can try `IsolationLevel.SnapShot` **on only the transaction that does long read-heavy work**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx

Extracted from the link:

> The term "snapshot" reflects the fact that all queries in the
> transaction see the same version, or snapshot, of the database, based
> on the state of the database at the moment in time when the
> transaction begins. **No locks are acquired** on the underlying data rows
> or data pages in a snapshot transaction, which permits other
> transactions to execute without being blocked by a prior uncompleted
> transaction. **Transactions that modify data do not block transactions
> that read data, and transactions that read data do not block
> transactions that write data**, as they normally would under the default
> READ COMMITTED isolation level in SQL Server. This non-blocking
> behavior also significantly reduces the likelihood of deadlocks for
> complex transactions.

Be aware that an enormous amount of data could be generated in `tempdb` for version store if there are a lot of modifications.

Comment: Cheers! Just to clarify, are you saying that if I use `Snapshot` on my long-running transaction, then I won't need to change anything on my other connections to stop them from locking?

Comment: @Matt Roberts: yes, but you need to consider concurrency control